# Partial derivative of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose;
\begin{array}{l}
de = fdt\\
V = {e^T}(t)\;P\;e(t)\; + \;\int\limits_{t - h}^t {{e^T}(\tau )\;Q\;e} (\tau )\;d\tau 
\end{array}

Does the following equation hold?!

\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial t}} + \frac{{\partial V}}{{\partial e}}\;f\;\mathop  = \limits^? \;\left( {\frac{{dV}}{{dt}}or\;\dot V} \right)
\end{array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABudB.png) solves the problem.